# Query applying Where clause BEFORE Joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm honestly really confused here, so I'll try to keep it simple.

We have Table A:
id

Table B:
id || number

Table A is a "prefilter" to B, since B contains a lot of different objects, including A.

So my query, trying to get all A's with a filter;

```
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(b.number, 2, 30) AS integer) between 151843 and 151865
```

Since ALL instances of A starts with a letter ("X******"), I just want to truncate the first letter to let the filter do his work with the number specified by the user.

At first glance, there should be absolutely no worries. But it seems I was wrong. And on something I didn't expect to be...

It seems like my WHERE clause is executed BEFORE my JOIN. Therefore, since many B's have number with more than one Letter at the start, I have an invalid conversion happening. Despite the fact that it would NEVER happen if we stay in A's.

I always thought that where clause was executed after joins, but in this case, it seems postgres wants to prove me wrong.

Any explanations ?

SQLFiddle demonstrating problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd7e6e/7

And even with the SubQuery, it still makes the same error...

Comment: Hi, Can you show that on the http://sqlfiddle.com/. It would be helpful.

Comment: please update the question with sample input data and expected result.

Comment: I thought postgres substring took the form of `substring(string [from int] [for int])` like `substring('Thomas' from 2 for 3)`. Does it work with commas too?

Comment: @Andreas yes, it does. Look up `substr()` function here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex substr function to remove everything but digits: `CAST(substring(B.number from '\d') AS integer)`.

See working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd7e6e/18

Comment: Great, though I agree with the notes in the answer by @Andreas, that you shouldn't assume the _how_, especially if you hop between databases. Also I should point out that if you need to use the number part of the column, then it should be split from the prefix and stored separately. Of course, the solution must be pragmatic and work with what you have, so you might consider this solution is adequate and justified.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a declarative language. For a select statement, you declare the criteria the data you are looking for must meet. You don't get to choose the execution path, your query isn't executed procedurally.

Thus the optimizer is free to choose any execution plan it likes, as long as it returns records specified by your criteria.

I suggest you change your query to cast to string instead of to integer. Something like:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(b.number, 2, 30) between CAST(151843 AS varchar) and CAST(151865 AS varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the records of A that are in B have the same id in table B as in A. If those records are inserted in a different order, this may not be the case and therefore return different records than expected.

Comment: No, they have exactly the same IDs and will always have.

    SELECT b.number FROM A a
    JOIN B b ON b.id = a.id

Returns only the records I expect to filter on.